# Функция выполняется до внесения изменений в базу?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, yii

Проект для учета рабочего времени. Есть таблица с днями месяца определенного сотрудника. Добавляю в нее день:

```
// Coхранение изменений
        if (!$intersection) {
            $day = $month_row->dayExists($_POST['day']) ? $days_model->findByPk($_POST['day_id']) : new $days_model();
            $day->month_id = $month_row->id;
            $day->day = $_POST['day'];
            $day->type = $_POST['day_type'];
            $day->start_time = $input_start;
            $day->end_time   = $input_end;
            $day->long_time  = $_POST['long_time'];
            $day->lunch_time = $_POST['lunch_time'];
            $day->save(false);
        }
```

После этого, сразу, вызываю функцию, которая считает итоговую информацию за месяц:

```
$total = $this->calculateTotal($month_row, $mode);
```

В ней не учитывается только что созданный день. Такое ощущение, что функция отрабатывает до того, как день был создан в таблице. При этом, что примечательно, если вызвать эту же функцию позже, то она считает этот "новый" день.

Кусок кода побольше. Функция сохранения изменений дня:

```
public function actionAjax_saveTimeChange() {

    if (!Y::isAjaxRequest()) {
        throw new CHttpException(404);
    }

    $_POST['long_time']  = round($_POST['long_time'], 1);
    $_POST['lunch_time'] = round($_POST['lunch_time'], 1);

    $d = array();

    // Для табеля и графика используются разные дни
    $mode = $_POST['mode'];
    $days_model = ($mode == 'graph') ? GraphDays::model() : TimesheetDays::model();

    // Запись в таблице месяц, к которой относится день
    $month_row = Months::model()->findByPk($_POST['month_id']);

    // Создаем дату начала и окончания нового периода
    $date = $month_row->year . "-" . str_pad($month_row->month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "-" . str_pad($_POST['day'], 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $input = $this->convertDayToDate($date, $_POST['start_time'], $_POST['long_time'], $_POST['lunch_time']);
    $input_start = $input['start'];
    $input_end = $input['end'];

    // Проверка пересечений времени
    $intersection = false;

    /*
     * Если тип дня "не рабочий"
     */

    if ($_POST['day_type'] != "РАБ") {
        $day = $month_row->dayExists($_POST['day']) ? $days_model->findByPk($_POST['day_id']) : new $days_model();
        $day->month_id = $month_row->id;
        $day->day = $_POST['day'];
        $day->type = $_POST['day_type'];
        $day->start_time = $input_start;
        $day->end_time   = $input_end;
        $day->long_time  = $_POST['long_time'];
        $day->lunch_time = $_POST['lunch_time'];
        $day->save(false);

        print json_encode(array(
            'success' => true,
            'inputStart' => date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($input_start)),
            'inputEnd' => date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($input_end)),
            'totaly' => $this->calculateTotal($month_row, $mode),
            'info' => $d
        ));

        return;
    }

    /*
     * Проверяем пересечение с отрезками времени текущей ставки
     */

    // Предыдущий день

    $prev_day_num = intval($_POST['day']) - 1;
    $next_day_num = intval($_POST['day']) + 1;

    $intersect_prev_day = false;

    if ($prev_day_num >= 1) {
        $prev_day = $days_model->findByAttributes(array(
            'month_id' => $month_row->id,
            'day' => $prev_day_num,
        ));
        if ($prev_day != null && $prev_day->type == 'РАБ') {
            $intersect_prev_day = $input_start <= $prev_day->end_time; //date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($month_row->year.'-'.$month_row->month.'-'.$prev_day->day.' '.substr($prev_day->end_time, 0, 5)));
            $d['prev_day_end'] = $prev_day->end_time;
        }
    } else {
        $prev_month = $month_row->month - 1 > 0 ? $month_row->month - 1 : 12;
        $prev_year  = $month_row->month - 1 > 0 ? intval($month_row->year) : intval($month_row->year) - 1;

        $prev_row = Months::model()->findByAttributes(array(
            'person_uid' => $month_row->person_uid,
            'person_post' => $month_row->person_post,
            'rate' => $month_row->rate,
            'month' => $prev_month,
            'year' => $prev_year
        ));

        if ($prev_row) {
            $prev_day = $days_model->findByAttributes(array(
                'month_id' => $prev_row->id,
                'day' => cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $prev_row->month, $prev_row->year),
            ));
            if ($prev_day != null && $prev_day->type == 'РАБ') {
                $intersect_prev_day = $input_start <= $prev_day->end_time; //date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($month_row->year.'-'.$month_row->month.'-'.$prev_day->day.' '.substr($prev_day->end_time, 0, 5)));
                $d['prev_day_end'] = $prev_day->end_time;
            }
        }
    }

    // Следующий день

    $intersect_next_day = false;

    if ($next_day_num <= cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month_row->month, $month_row->year)) {
        $next_day = $days_model->findByAttributes(array(
            'month_id' => $month_row->id,
            'day' => $next_day_num,
        ));
        if ($next_day != null && $next_day->type == 'РАБ') {
            $intersect_next_day = $input_end >= $next_day->start_time; //date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($month_row->year.'-'.$month_row->month.'-'.$next_day->day.' '.substr($next_day->start_time, 0, 5)));\
            $d['next_day_start'] = $next_day->start_time;
        }
    } else {
        $next_month = $month_row->month + 1 > 12 ? 1 : $month_row->month + 1;
        $next_year  = $month_row->month + 1 > 12 ? intval($month_row->year) + 1 : intval($month_row->year);

        $next_row = Months::model()->findByAttributes(array(
            'person_uid' => $month_row->person_uid,
            'person_post' => $month_row->person_post,
            'rate' => $month_row->rate,
            'month' => $next_month,
            'year' => $next_year
        ));

        if ($next_row) {
            $next_day = $days_model->findByAttributes(array(
                'month_id' => $next_row->id,
                'day' => 1,
            ));
            if ($next_day != null && $next_day->type == 'РАБ') {
                $intersect_next_day = $input_end >= $next_day->start_time;//date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($next_row->year.'-'.$next_row->month.'-'.$next_day->day.' '.substr($next_day->start_time, 0, 5)));
                $d['next_day_start'] = $next_day->start_time;
            }
        }
    }

    $intersection = $intersect_prev_day || $intersect_next_day;

    $d[] = array(
        '$intersection' => $intersection,
        '$input_start' => $input_start,
        '$input_end' => $input_end,
        '$intersect_next_day' => $intersect_next_day,
        '$intersect_prev_day' => $intersect_prev_day,
        'long_time' => $_POST['long_time'],
        'long_time_convert' => Y::toFloat($_POST['long_time'])
    );

    /*
     * Проверяем пересечение с другими ставками
     */

    $trace = array();

    if (!$intersection) {

        $trace[] = '!$intersection';

        $person_rows = Months::model()->findAll(array(
            'condition' => 'person_uid = "' . $month_row->person_uid . '" AND year = ' . $month_row->year . ' AND month = ' . $month_row->month . " AND id <> " . $month_row->id
        ));

        $input = $this->convertDayToDate($date, $_POST['start_time'], $_POST['long_time'], $_POST['lunch_time']);
        $input_start = $input['start'];
        $input_end = $input['end'];

        if ($_POST['day_type'] == 'РАБ') {
            $trace[] = " (_POST[day_type] == РАБ) ";
            foreach ($person_rows as $row) {
                foreach (($mode == 'graph' ? $row->graphDays : $row->tabelDays) as $day) {
                    if ($day != null && $day->type == 'РАБ') {
                        $trace[] = $day->day;

                        $check_start = (($input_start >= $day->start_time) && ($input_start < $day->end_time));
                        $check_end = (($input_end >= $day->start_time) && ($input_end < $day->end_time));
                        $intersection = $check_start || $check_end;

                        $trace[] = "check_start=" . $input_start ." >= " . $day->start_time." && ".$input_start . " < " . $day->end_time . " === " . $check_start;
                        $trace[] = "check_end=" . $input_end ." >= " . $day->start_time." && ".$input_end . " < " . $day->end_time . " === " . $check_end;

                        if ($intersection) {
                            $intersect_day = $day->day;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($intersection) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Coхранение изменений
        if (!$intersection) {
            $day = $month_row->dayExists($_POST['day']) ? $days_model->findByPk($_POST['day_id']) : new $days_model();
            $day->month_id = $month_row->id;
            $day->day = $_POST['day'];
            $day->type = $_POST['day_type'];
            $day->start_time = $input_start;
            $day->end_time   = $input_end;
            $day->long_time  = $_POST['long_time'];
            $day->lunch_time = $_POST['lunch_time'];
            $day->save(false);
        }
    }

    $total = $this->calculateTotal($month_row, $mode);

    if ($mode == "graph") {
        $time = TotalTimeGraph::model()->findByAttributes(array(
            "month_id" => $_POST['month_id']
        ));
        //$time->month_id = $_POST['month_id'];
        $time->days = $total['total_days'];
        $time->hours = $total['total_hours'];
        $time->night_hours = $total['night_hours'];
        $time->normal_hours = $total['normal_hours'];
        $time->deviation_hours = $total['deviation_hours'];
        $time->save(false);
    } else {
        $time = TotalTimeTimesheet::model()->findByAttributes(array(
            "month_id" => $_POST['month_id']
        ));
        //$time->month_id = $_POST['month_id'];
        $time->days = $total['total_days'];
        $time->hours = $total['total_hours'];
        $time->night_hours = $total['night_hours'];
        $time->normal_hours = $total['normal_hours'];
        $time->deviation_hours = $total['deviation_hours'];
        $time->holiday_hours = $total['holiday_hours'];
        $time->days_15 = $total['days_15'];
        $time->hours_15 = $total['hours_15'];
        $time->night_hours_15 = $total['night_hours_15'];
        $time->holiday_hours_15 = $total['holiday_hours_15'];
        $time->save(false);
    }

    print json_encode(array(
        //'next_day' => $next_day,
        '$intersection' => $intersection,
        'trace' => $trace,
        //'condition' => 'person_uid = "' . $month_row->person_uid . '" AND year = ' . $month_row->year . ' AND month = ' . $month_row->month . " AND id <> " . $month_row->id,
        //'intersection_prev_day' => $intersect_prev_day,
        //'intersection_next_day' => $intersect_next_day,
        'success' => !$intersection,
        'inputStart' => $input_start,
        'inputEnd' => $input_end,
        'totaly' => $this->calculateTotal($month_row, $mode),
        //'info' => $d
    ));
}
```

**UPD**

Я случайно нашел решение (да-да, костыль). Вот такой код - не правильно работает:

```
$month_row = Months::model()->findByPk($_POST['month_id']);
```

А такой - работает как надо:

```
$month_row = Months::model()->findByPk($_POST['month_id']);
$total = $this->calculateTotal($month_row, $mode);
```

Т.е. я дергаю из базы инфу о месяце. Как это помогло - я не понимаю. У кого-то есть соображения?

Comment: что значит *если вызвать эту же функцию позже*? сделать перед нею `sleep(5)` или вызвать ее после некоторых действия (тогда после каких)? У вас может не срабатывает условие `if (!$intersection) {...}`, т.е. вы и не добавляете ничего перед вызовом `calculateTotal`

Comment: Вызвать позже - это вызвать после добавления дня. Со sleep  я пробовал экспериментировать - при его использовании, почему то, проблема остается.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов А зачем в вопросе тег "mysql", как вопрос его касается ? У вас вопрос исключительно про работу ваших классов, ни единого sql запроса в вопросе не видно. База тут то же не причем, ей сказали - она сохранила, не сказали, не сохранила. А скорее всего ваши классы в базу записали, а другие классы взяли данные из кеша и ничего не пересчитывали а при следующем запуске кеша нет - они берут из базы

Comment: @Mike, я не знаю в чем проблема. Классы Active Record в Yii в конечном итоге сводятся к выполнению MySQL запросов, т.е. к работе с базой. Я предположил, что могут иметься какие то особенности работы БД которые связаны с моей проблемой и о которых я не знаю. По моему, это очевидно.

Comment: @ИльяБизунов В базах таких особенностей, не позволяющих той же сессии, что записала данные их не видеть - не бывает. тут явно классы что то мудрят. А может расчет довольно сложная операция и она запускается в фоне отдельно от вашего процесса (правда за это опять же отвечает не база, а некие скрипты)

Comment: @Mike, нет, расчет хоть и имеет довольно запутанную логику, но выполняется он очень быстро.

Answer (score 1):

Весь код (ту часть где происходит сохранение и вызов Вашей функции) Вы не предоставили. Из Вашего вопроса предположу что можно решить проблему так:

В Yii2 (в Yii1 без параметров, честно не помню уже) )

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    if ($insert)
    {
      // о да, запись создана )
      $total = $this->calculateTotal($month_row, $mode);
    }
    else
    {
      // wtf
    }
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
}
```

Comment: Добавил функцию в пост. По поводу afterSave - я не понял, зачем это использовать. Если бы функция calculateTotal "ждала" пока произойдет вставка - тогда да, было бы круто. А сейчас это такой же код, как и у меня, просто выполняется в другом месте. Или я не прав?

Comment: _После этого, сразу, вызываю функцию, которая считает итоговую информацию за месяц:

$total = $this->calculateTotal($month_row, $mode);
В ней не учитывается только что созданный день. Такое ощущение, что функция отрабатывает до того, как день был создан в таблице._  
Из этого я понял, что Ваша функция должна сделать вычисления с учетом последнего добавленного дня. И да (из Вашего описания в вопросе), она должна выполниться после добавления записи. Или Вы имели ввиду что-то другое и я Вас не понял )

Comment: Нет-нет, Вы все правильно поняли. Меня лишь смущает то, что в вашем примере по сути, выполняется все так же, как и у меня - вставка, а за ней сразу подсчет.

Comment: _ При этом, что примечательно, если вызвать эту же функцию позже, то она считает этот "новый" день._
И Ваш комментарий к комменту товарища @ВОРОН
_Вызвать позже - это вызвать после добавления дня._
Так вызывайте после добавления дня )
можно же еще так сделать `if ($day->save(false)) {$this->calculateTotal($month_row, $mode);}`
Честно говоря я уже сам запутался в Вашем вопросе, как-то все неоднозначно )

Comment: А, понял. Вот пример: отредактировали мы день 12, например. Шлем запрос на сервер, он сохраняет день и считает итог. В итоге не учитывается введенный нами день. Редактируем, например, 13-й день, также идет запрос на сервак, добавляется 13-й день, идет подсчет итога. В результат этого подсчета, 12-й день уже попадает, а 13-й, только что введенный - нет.